# Use a Command with TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I would like to call a Command when a TabItem of my TabControl is selected.

Is there a way to do it without breaking the MVVM pattern ?

Comment: You can also bind to IsSelected and handle changes to that property in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [AttachedCommand Behavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/), which will let you bind a Command to WPF events

```
<TabControl ...
    local:CommandBehavior.Event="SelectionChanged"  
    local:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding TabChangedCommand}" />
```

Of course, if you're using the MVVM design pattern and binding `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex`, you could also run the command in the `PropertyChanged` event

```
void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedIndex")
        RunTabChangedLogic();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It can be done using the following classes together:

- `EventTrigger` class from the `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace (`System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly).
- `EventToCommand` class from the `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command` namespace ([MVVM Light Toolkit](http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/) assembly, for example, `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4`):

XAML:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command
        ...>
...
    <TabControl>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TabSelectionChangedCommand}"
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <TabItem>...</TabItem>
        <TabItem>...</TabItem>
    </TabControl>
...
</Window>
```

Create an instance of the command in the `ViewModel` constructor:

```
TabSelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(args =>
    {
        // Command action.
    });
```

Comment: That's just `Interactivity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801), you don't need any MVVM framework to use this.

Comment: @H.B., it is correct for the `EventTrigger` class. But the `EventToCommand` class belongs to the MVVM Light Toolkit.