# WPF TabControl: How to Pass TabItem Header Text to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need to pass the TabItem header string from xaml to ViewModel where i will use this text to fire
an event, so when i select any tab in the tabcontrol, the tabitem header will be sent to the viewmodel to fire the event.
Also i need this scenario to take place when selecting the tabitem header not any part else on the tab.It is a Tabbed interface aplication.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435907/use-a-command-with-tabitem

i think this could do the trick .

Comment: @eranotzap: thanks for response, but my main issue is to pass the text displayed in the tab header to the view model.

Comment: i thought you could fire a command , another way i could think of
is to check if the TabControl has a selected item , bind a property of selected TabItem's header in your VM .